# Symbol and principal symbol of differential operator

Tags: polynomials, partial-differential-equations

The symbol of a differential operator is defined as

$L(x,p):=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m}a_\alpha(x)p^\alpha$

and the principal symbol $L^p(x,p)$ is defined similar but with $|a|=m$.

What would be the symbol and the principal symbol of the differential operator

$$Lu=\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}u(x,y)-2\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}u(x,y)+\frac{\partial^4}{\partial y^4}u(x,y)$$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ for example?

By definition, they are polynomials. Is the principal symbol $x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4=(x^2-y^2)^2$? But it should be a polynomial in $p$, not in $x$, which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol would be $$L(x,p)=p_1^4-2p_1^2p_2^2+p_2^4. $$ This is essentially what you have, but you shouldn't use $x$ and $y$. For example, if instead you had

$$Lu=x^2\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}u(x,y)-2y\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}u(x,y)+\frac{\partial^4}{\partial y^4}u(x,y)$$ then the symbol would be $$L(x,y,p)=x^2p_1^4-2yp_1^2p_2^2+p_2^4 $$ so using $x,y$ leads to confusion.

---

As you mention the principle symbol is given by $$ \sum_{\vert \alpha \vert =m} a_\alpha(x)p^\alpha.$$ What this amounts to is, if your operator is 4-th order, then to obtain the principle symbol from the symbol you simply 'through away' the terms that are not fourth order. In your case, every monomial in your symbol is of order four, so the symbol is the same as the principle symbol. If, for example, you had  $$Lu=x^2\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}u(x,y)-2y\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}u(x,y)+\frac{\partial^4}{\partial y^4}u(x,y)+xy\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)$$ then the symbol is $$x^2p_1^4-2yp_1^2p_2^2+p_2^4+xyp_1, $$ but the principle symbol is  $$x^2p_1^4-2yp_1^2p_2^2+p_2^4. $$

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between the symbol and the principal symbol in my example?